# New Linked list contains the previous one

Tags: c, linked-list

I have linked lists that represents integers (each node is a digit from the integer). After making a second or a third linked list when i try to print them, in the second one prints the 2nd and the 1st, in the 3nd, prints 3nd,2nd and 1st together etc. What am i missing? Any help is welcome....
The struct of each node that i use is:

```
typedef struct node {
int digit;
struct node *next;
} listnode_t;
```

For example this is my main

main

```
listnode_t *number1 = create_list(2);//create list of two digits
listnode_t *number2 = create_list(2);//create list of two digits
listnode_t *number3 = int_to_list(1024);//create list for integer 1024
print_number(number1);
printf("\n");
print_number(number2);
printf("\n");
print_number(number3);
```

and my output is

```
Give a digit: 1
Give a digit: 7
Give a digit: 9
Give a digit: 5
17
End of printing number
9517
End of printing number
10249517
End of printing nunmber
```

The three methods i use are:
print_number(listnode_t *head) 
Takes a pointer on head of a list and print the elements

```
void print_number(listnode_t *head){

listnode_t *anode = head;

if (anode == NULL){

    printf("The list is empty\n");
}

else {


        while(anode != NULL){
        printf("%d",anode->digit);
        anode = anode->next;

            }
        printf("\n");
        printf("End of printing the number\n");

    }
}
```

the listnode_t *create_list(int numdigits)

```
listnode_t *create_list(int numdigits){


listnode_t *ptr2;
listnode_t *head2;

int i;
int num[numdigits];
for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++){
    do{
    printf("Give a digit: ");
    scanf("%d",&num[i]);
    } while (num[i]>9 || num[i]<0);
}

    for(i=numdigits-1;i>=0;i--){
    ptr2 = (listnode_t*)malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
    if (ptr2 == NULL){

    printf("\n Node creation failed \n");
    return NULL;
}


ptr2->digit = num[i];
ptr2->next = NULL;

ptr2->next = head2;
head2 = ptr2;

}

return ptr2;    

}
```

and the listnode_t *int_to_list(int num)
that takes an integer and represent it as a linked list from LSB to MSB

```
listnode_t *int_to_list(int num) {

listnode_t *ptr1;
listnode_t *head1;


int numOfdigits = countdigits(num);//counts the number of digits of integer 
                                   //num
int k = numOfdigits;
int digits[numOfdigits];
while (numOfdigits--) {
digits[numOfdigits]=num%10;
num/=10;

}


int i;
for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--){
    ptr1 = (listnode_t*)malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
        if (ptr1 == NULL){

            printf("\n Node creation failed \n");
            return NULL;
}

ptr1->digit = digits[i];
ptr1->next = NULL;
ptr1->next = head1;
head1 = ptr1;


}

    return ptr1;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. It is hardly readable and doesn't invite help.

Comment: You need to initialize `head1` and `head2` to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott, now works as i want. I knew that something simple i was missing. Thanks again!